# What is this text near Iron Man's rockets?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

The following screenshot shows Iron Man's HUD from the movies. The circled section shows his current rocket inventory.

[image]

If you reverse the image and zoom in, you can see some additional text following the word 'Rockets'. **What does this text say?** Is it the type of missile that's currently equipped? Some other diagnostic? I can make out a few letters, but I wouldn't know how close I was with my guessing without more knowledge of the universe.

[image]

Comment: Could be: NEON POWERS, or MOON COWERS, or MEOW MIXERS, or WEXW FLOWERS

Comment: For a discrete item like rockets, when you're looking at the HUD, you'd rarely want to know that it's "97% full". What you'd want to know is that you have 29 rockets remaining in each magazine. Now, if it was counting something where it's rare to be counting single units (e.g. where you have a quite large capacity), then you're, probably, more interested in % remaining (e.g. 97% instead of 3,880 out of 4,000).

Comment: @Makyen - Perhaps the suit is capable of making more rockets over time.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### "WIDOW-MAKERS".

I found a higher definition (raw) image of the graphic used as an illustration in an interview with the VFX creator for the HUD in the Avengers film. The text is more readable.

[image]

<sub><sup>[Jayse Hansen on creating UI for The Avengers, touch control, holograms, Galaga and Project Glass](https://thenextweb.com/media/2012/06/02/jayse-hansen-on-creating-tools-the-avengers-use-to-fight-evil-touch-interfaces-and-project-glass/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I read it as WINDOW CLEANERS, obviously the rockets are specially designed for removing scum from windows.

Comment: For the record, I suspect that these are the little rockets he fired from his arm mount.

Comment: The odd thing is, the OP image is just after he put on the suit and switched to combat mode. Why weren't his rockets at 100%?

Comment: @JackBNimble - One in the chamber ready to fire

Comment: After you told me what it says, I can see it. But I can also still see *Meow Powers*.

Comment: @JackBNimble A better question would be why he needs a percentage for that small a number, especially as it already shows the number of missiles anyway.

Comment: @JAB If one missile is about 3%, he has at least 29 missiles. (More likely, he has 30 or more.) I don't see an actual number anywhere. Counting is a bad thing to need to do during combat, and the percentage also helps him keep track of how quickly he's using up weapons more easily.

Comment: I am enjoying the discussion about the percentage here and would like to suggest that Tony is simply a bad UX guy.

Comment: @JAB Showing a number requires him to remember the exact complement of missiles. For a smart guy like Tony Stark that might not be difficult, but given how many variants of suit he has, and how many gadgets each suit offers, it starts to become quite a lot to remember. If it said "23 remaining" he'd have to remember how many he started with - 23 of 25 is very different to 23 of 500, and this is important in combat when judging how quickly you're using up ammo. A percentage gives him the important info faster: "On a scale from FULL to EMPTY, where am I?"

Comment: I see MOON MAGNETS

Comment: @jpmc - Valorum's image shows 2% remaining, which means more than 40 (1/40 would usually round to 3%).

Comment: @Binaryfunt - Then you should get your eyes check checked

Comment: Doesn't he shoot at any females? Or unmarried males?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - His "Daddy issues" are widely known

Comment: @Jules Taking *both* images into consideration, it must be at least 58 rockets.

Comment: By the same token, the “one in the chamber ready to fire” explanation is incorrect. We know that one rocket rounds to at most 2%, not 3%.

Comment: @anaximander I'm sorry but what? How is knowing how much ammo he's used up _relatively_ better than knowing how much _actual_ shots he has left?

Comment: @cubic I suspect that the graphic with shaded or unshaded rocket icons tells him how many he has left ... at least when he gets close enough to need to worry about individual shots. But until he's down to the 20ish he vsn visuslize via thr icons, how quickly he's using the up does seem more important.